# Query cannot be translated EF Core 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I'm trying to execute this query:

```
await _tagRepository.DomainContext
                    .Tag
                    .Where(x => x.Id == tag.Id)  // tag.id contains an integer
                    .ExecuteUpdateAsync(s=> s.SetProperty(p => p.NumberOfMention, p => p.NumberOfMention + 1));
```

I'm getting an error:

> Where(t => t.Id == __tag_Id_0)
> .ExecuteUpdate(s => s.SetProperty(
> propertyExpression: p => p.NumberOfMention,
> valueExpression: 5))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,

Now I don't want to call enumerable, considering the tag table contains 1M records.

How can I modify the query?

Comment: why don't you `ExecuteUpdateAsync(s=> s.NumberOfMention = s.NumberOfMention+1)`?

Comment: just to note, I would not work with EF for 1M records

Comment: Are you positive the code you provided is the same as what's creating the error? The error you posted says `valueExpression` is `5`, which is not what your code is passing in.

Comment: Please share the `Tag` entity. Ideally provide a [mre].

Comment: @LeandroBardelli because...? If you use it properly, there is no problem working with 100M or as many records you want. Not to count that in this particular case it is just generating database agnostic SQL `UPDATE` statement using C#/LINQ syntax.

Comment: @IvanStoev I don't like the profiling of EF with that amount of data. That's why I said it's a personal election.